# Asp.Net set Visibility of Dropdown list inside gridview in aTemplate Field

Tags: asp.net

I have a Gridview with Template field

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Scoring">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlY_N_NA" runat="server"
            Visible='<%#Eval("IsTextBox")%>' ></asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAudit" runat="server"
            Visible='<%#Eval("IsTextBox")%>' ></asp:TextBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I need to set the visibility of drop down based on the visibility of Textbox.
Either of the two has to be shown per row but not both.
Can any help me in this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok I found the solution.

Comment: Would you provide the solution as an answer plz ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Scoring">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlY_N_NA" runat="server"
            Visible='<%# ((bool)Eval("IsTextBox")) ? "false" : "true" %>' >
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAudit" runat="server"
            Visible='<%#Eval("IsTextBox")%>' ></asp:TextBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the `RowDataBound` event of the Gridview.

```
 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DataRow dr = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;
        if (dr["ColumnName"].ToString()) // your Condition
        {
            ((DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("dropdownID")).Visible = false;
        }
        else if (dr["ColumnName"].ToString()) // your Condition
        {
            ((TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("TextboxID")).Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Hi, Akram Shahda below is my solution

```
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Scoring" HeaderStyle-Width="12%">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                                                     <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlY_N_NA" Visible='<%#SetVisibility(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"IsTextBox"))%>'
                                                    runat="server" CssClass="Qdropdown">
                                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                                <asp:TextBox onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event);" ID="txtAudit" Visible='<%#Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("IsTextBox"))%>'
                                                    MaxLength="10" runat="server" CssClass="Qinputbox" Width="54px" ValidationGroup="txt"></asp:TextBox>
                                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnTextBoxCondition" Value='<%#SetTextBoxVisibility(Eval("IsTextBox"),Eval("TextBoxConditions"))%>'
                                                    Visible='<%#Eval("IsTextBox")%>' runat="server" />

                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
```

In the code behind I have written the methods which will set the visibility

```
  public bool SetVisibility(object value)
{
    if (Convert.ToBoolean(value))
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
public string SetTextBoxVisibility(object value, object condition)
{

    if (Convert.ToBoolean(value))
        return Convert.ToString(condition);
    else
        return "";
}
```